# how to install PySide6 in Raspbian running in a virtual machine

Tags: python, pip, virtual-machine, version, raspbian

I am running Raspbian OS in a virtual machine on windows. I want to install PySide6 in that Raspbian OS. I am getting following error,

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside6
> (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyside6

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi,

Run `pip --version` and post the version

Run `python --version ` and post the version

Comment: pip 18.1 from /home/pi/Downloads/pysideApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: python version is 3.7.3

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade pip` and run PySide6 install again

Comment: yes, I have done this, not success yet.

Answer (score 0):

From this post: https://forum.qt.io/topic/135892/installing-pyside-on-a-raspberry-pi/5

Currently, PySide6 doesn't have released package on Raspbian OS. You may try Manjaro on Raspberry Pi if the hardware platform is specified.

Comment: Please consider adding relevant quotes from the qt forum topic, since the link may be broken in the future. Your answer will then be self-sufficient, and still give the original reference (should the url survive the next 5+ years >.<)