# Error installing PySide6 on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: python-3.x, qt-creator, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, pyside6

I created a project using QTcreator with PySide6 and cv2 on a Ubuntu Linux computer, and it worked very well. However, when I transferred this project to my Raspberry Pi4, problems arose.

I tried to install the PySide6 library using sudo pip install pyside6, but I received the following error message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside6
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyside6

I also tried to ask ChatGPT, but none of the options provided worked, such as manually downloading and unpacking the file, downloading and unpacking via the terminal, downloading to a different directory, and downloading separate functions. All of these options failed.

I have QTcreator installed on my Raspberry Pi4, but I would like to know how I can run my script.

Note: There are other similar posts to this, but none of them were able to solve my problem.

Comment: That's because there are no official PySide packages in pip for that platform, as written in probably any post you found yet: you either use another distro (which builds it on its own), or you build it on your own. And an AI won't certainly help you a lot with that (so, there's really no point in highlighting it), especially considering that it only has information up to late 2021/early2022.

Comment: @musicamante would there be any way to use qt in raspbarry?

Comment: First of all, remember that Qt is a C++ library, and it's probably already installed on your system at least for version 5, *possibly* also for version 6. What you're referring to, instead, is PySide, which is a *python binding* to that library, and if you want to use PySide6 (that is bound to Qt6) then, as said, either you build it on your own, or use a distro that has it already builtin. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70272508

Comment: I will rewrite the code in c+. I believe this solves the problem then?

Comment: If that's a feasible option for you, then it's fine, *assuming* that you *do* have Qt6 installed there. But if you're experienced in C++, you probably wouldn't have too many problems in building PySide on your own. Also, unless you specifically need features that only Qt6 provides, why don't you just use PySide2 (aka: Qt5)?

Comment: i tried to install other versions of pyside and Qt on my raspbarry but they all return error during installation